# VirtualBox USB device error NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 VirtualBox 4.3

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I have been trying to connect my new Boogie Board sync to a virtualbox 4.3 virtual machine running on an ubuntu 14.04 host. I keep running into this NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) and have not been able to resolve it, despite trying it a number of different ways.

Note I did look up a few different existing posts, but they did not help. The issues are different than the one that I am running into and the software versions are different too. But here are the ones I looked at.

[Virtualbox does not run: NS_ERROR_FAILURE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217972/virtualbox-does-not-run-ns-error-failure)

[What is holding my USB device when I try to use it in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484565/what-is-holding-my-usb-device-when-i-try-to-use-it-in-virtualbox)

The error message I get says

```
Failed to attach the USB device Improv Electronics Sync [0120] to the virtual machine        
IE11 - Win8.1_1. Failed to create a proxy device for the USB device. (Error:     
VERR_READ_ERROR).
```

The message details indicate

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Note I am using the Windows 8.1 virtual machine from Microsoft, but I don't believe that makes any difference.

Things I have tried:

1. enabled USB controller on the virtualbox manager with the EHCI controller.
2. tried enabled USB controller without the EHCI controller.
3. tried to rebuild the virtualbox image from scratch.
4. added myself to the vboxusers group.

None of this has seemed to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you the VB extensions installed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox does not run: NS\_ERROR\_FAILURE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217972/virtualbox-does-not-run-ns-error-failure)

Answer (score 2):

USB devices can either be used on your host OS or guest OS, but not shared between both. Whatever captures the USB device first, will block communication for the other system.

You should have the [VirtualBox extensions pack installed](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.0-101573.vbox-extpack), which enables USB 2.

Then you need to [install the VirtualBox guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp90764336) in your virtual machine.

Next you need to start the VM, go into the machine settings and choose Ports/USB. Then select the <kbd>+</kbd> icon and add the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody bumps to this in the future. It may be that the required packages are not among dependencies. In my case, running through the terminal throws:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
```

Installing **virtualbox-dkms** solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: `Error: Unable to find a match`

Comment: Really? There should still be such a package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox-dkms&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all

Comment: Works for me still.

Comment: I also needed to install virtualbox-ext-pack and then could use USB 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The most simple decision, that I found is to enter into the folder `/home/$user/.VirtualBox/` find there file `VirtualBox.xml-prev` delete `VirtualBox.xml` and change name `VirtualBox.xml-prev` on `VirtualBox.xml`. That backed up your configurations of Virtual Box.

Comment: thanks @Skynet , I tried to do this, but still no luck. I am still getting the same error. No change in the error specified either. The host device recognizes the usb device but I cannot get the virtualbox image to recognize it. I even tried reinstalling the virtualbox image a few times, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have replayed to [similar question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217972/virtualbox-does-not-run-ns-error-failure/685596#685596).

> A simple command can fix your problem:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
> ```